# Google maps polylines with space between them

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

On google maps API-V3; the only way to show the steps along a path shown by polylines is to set an ugly marker at the polyline joints. Instead; is there anyway to shorten the ends of a polyline?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a polyline without showing markers, setting them to `visible: false`. Can you explain "shorten the ends"? You mean move the endpoints along the segment so the length decreases? How would you decide how far? Percentage?

http://jsfiddle.net/AZpPd/